# Is it possible not to display INSERT FAILED Error in page, when our custom validation error is triggered

Tags: trigger, dmlexception, adderror

We have a visualforce page (Manage Packaged) that saves a record. We added a custom validation using trigger (addError method) to prevent it to save when a certain criteria is met. But when this is triggered, two errors are getting displayed (shown below). Is it possible not to display the second error considering that the code at the record is inserted is managed?

> You can only match one invoice at a time
>
> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, You can only match one invoice at atime: []